# Numpy Installation Issue in FreeBSD 12

Tags: python, numpy, gcc, freebsd

I have FreeBSD[12.2-stable] I installed numpy[1.24.1] via package manager.
pkg install py39-numpy
After installation,
I use Python3.9 and try to import
It says libgfortran.so.5 sterror_l symbol not found.

I want to successfully install numpy and import it successfully.
I tried to install from source. But Compilation issue. Python.h failed to compile install Python3-devel. I did not find Python3-devel in FreeBSD

Comment: Your environment is not clear, eg `I have FreeBSD-12` : no, you didn't. `FreeBSD-12.4` is probably what you have. Plz be more accurate on what you have (full version), from what you get it (ports tree or package) ; Python rely on the `lang` branch, not the `devel` branch. `numpy` is know to have versioning issue, you have to check what you really have and what version.

Comment: I got it from package as I mentioned. Python 3.9.16 installed via package manager[pkg. Numpy 1.24.1 installed via package manager[pkg install py39-numpy],

Comment: What does [tag:pfsense] have with any of this to do anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have enough 'reputation' to leave a comment, I will give my (hopefully helpful) answer:

If the question to be answered is "How can I install numpy v1.24.1 or higher on FreeBSD 12.x?", my answer is this. Uninstall the package, `# pkg delete numpy`. Then, as your regular user, use pip to install numpy, `$ pip install numpy`. This *should* give you a working numpy install.

I use numpy on my 14.0-RELEASE-p4 system regularly.
`$ pkg info numpy`
`pkg: No package(s) matching numpy`

`$ pip freeze | grep numpy`
`numpy==1.26.3`

I truly hope this helps. Please report back. :-)

Comment: Yes, you should avoid installing something like numpy system-wide. Use a virtual environment and install with pip. I've done this in FreeBSD with no problems.